# How to express the process of number of stock (nt) in a portfolio using ito's lemma

Tags: time-series, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, itos-lemma

We have a regular self-financing portfolio $W_t$:
$$dW_t = n_t dS_t + (W_t − n_t S_t) r dt$$
Where $W_t$ is total wealth, $n_t$ is amount of stock, $S_t$ is stock price, $r$ is the risk-free rate.
And the strategy is to keep the stock exposure φ constant：

$φ = n_t S_t/W_t$

Currently I'm having trouble while trying to develop a formula for $n_t$, using $dS_t$ and $dt$.

Comment: my suggestion is to look at the literature and blog posts around the [Merton portfolio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton%27s_portfolio_problem) or the [Stochastic Portfolio Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_portfolio_theory) they both deeply rely on being able to compute this.